# How can I fix the error " unrecognized selector sent to instance..."?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I tried this site's `Xcode` project.

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-building-advanced-rss-reader-with-ios6/

But I couldn't get information of RSS because of the error:

```
-[RSSItem setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f875bd8e010"
```

and

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[RSSItem setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f875bd8e010
```

I tried to make break points in `RSSItem.h file` and investigated this error.

But I don't find the cause...

Comment: Give details of the test you ran. What rss were you processing?

Comment: Change the property Description in RSSItem.h to @property (retain,nonatomic) DATATYPE * Description;

Comment: I used the feed URL "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TouchCodeMagazine"

Comment: I changed  property  (strong... to  property (retain.... but the error didn't solve.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change "description" to "Description" so I couldn't solve it.but even I changed it, the error " parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined " has caused in some website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is quite old and is based on iOS 6.
Since iOS 8 the NSObject protocol (which is inherited by all objects based on NSObject) has [defined](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) the `description` property as a read-only string.  Properties cannot be overridden in a subclass, so your attempt to create a read/write `description` property won't work.

You should use some other property name, such as `itemDescription` rather than `description`.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I forgot to change "description" to "Description".So I couldn't .... but even I changed it, I couldn't use some website's RSS and caused many parser error like "Entity 'nbsp' not defined"....

Comment: I would use `itemDescription` rather than `Description` as a property with a capital first letter doesn't comply with standard style.  Your other errors sound like issues with XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the property name 'description' collides with the 'description' read-only property of NSObject (and is therefore more or less a reserved name in Objective-C). Check your build log for a warning on the 'description' property. 
I suggest renaming this RSSItem property to something else.